# Use of a method other than Main

Tags: java, program-entry-point

This is a Java newbie so apologies for the simple questions !

What i want to do is actually testing a method other than Main in my Java class. So my questions are several fold.

Lets say my sample code is as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}   

public static void sampleMethod(boolean condition)  {       
    System.out.println(condition);  
}
```

I want to test sampleMethod with a test case. As i have read Main has to initiate other methods so according to that information i update my code as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sampleMethod(true); 
}   

public static void sampleMethod(boolean condition)  {       
    System.out.println(condition);  
}
```

As i would like to pass the parameter from the test case, whatever parameter i call the Main with should be passed to the sampleMethod. But when i update the code as below, this causes an error as Main method seems accept String arg whilst i would like to pass a boolean parameter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sampleMethod(args); 
}   

public static void sampleMethod(boolean condition)  {       
    System.out.println(condition);  
}
```

Could anyone tell how can i overcome this ?

Many thanks

Reha

Comment: You need to pass a boolean.

Comment: What is the information in `args` that you are trying to pass to `sampleMethod`?

Answer (score 0):

So in command prompt call: `java MyProgram true` or `java MyProgram false`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    sampleMethod(Boolean.valueOf(args[0])); // first argument 
}
```

Comment: Try running that and see what happens. (Hint, it won't work).

Comment: yes but shouldn't the method call be `sampleMethod(args[0]);` instead of just `sampleMethod(args);` ?